# Wrong colors in pgfplots colorbar when using option colormap access=piecewise constant

Tags: pgfplots, color, viewers

I am trying to generate a contour plot with colorbar.
The following example does look fine in TeXworks, however in an older version of Adobe and Foxit the colorbar does not show the right colors. This is shown in the picture below.

[image]

If the option `colormap access=piecewise constant` is removed the colorbar looks good in all viewers but is interpolated. What am I doing wrong here?

```
\documentclass[paper=A5]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
0.000000e+00    4.000000e+00
3.300000e+01    4.000000e+01
3.250000e+01    3.600000e+01
3.150000e+01    3.400000e+01
2.900000e+01    3.250000e+01
2.000000e+00    5.300000e+01
3.308081e+01    2.800000e+01
3.300000e+01    2.766667e+01
3.227273e+01    2.800000e+01
3.200000e+01    2.813043e+01
3.100000e+01    2.863636e+01
3.033333e+01    2.900000e+01
3.000000e+01    2.919048e+01
2.900000e+01    2.980000e+01
2.869231e+01    3.000000e+01
2.800000e+01    3.047368e+01
2.728571e+01    3.100000e+01
2.700000e+01    3.122222e+01
2.606667e+01    3.200000e+01
2.600000e+01    3.205882e+01
2.500000e+01    3.300000e+01
2.600000e+01    3.322857e+01
2.700000e+01    3.353333e+01
2.800000e+01    3.396000e+01
2.807692e+01    3.400000e+01
2.900000e+01    3.460000e+01
2.944444e+01    3.500000e+01
3.000000e+01    3.566667e+01
3.021739e+01    3.600000e+01
3.071429e+01    3.700000e+01
3.100000e+01    3.780000e+01
3.106061e+01    3.800000e+01
3.131579e+01    3.900000e+01
3.151163e+01    4.000000e+01
3.166667e+01    4.100000e+01
3.182927e+01    4.200000e+01
3.200000e+01    4.277778e+01
3.205882e+01    4.300000e+01
3.240741e+01    4.400000e+01
3.300000e+01    4.500000e+01
3.330476e+01    4.400000e+01
3.358182e+01    4.300000e+01
3.383478e+01    4.200000e+01
3.400000e+01    4.129630e+01
3.406667e+01    4.100000e+01
3.408475e+01    4.000000e+01
3.410345e+01    3.900000e+01
3.412281e+01    3.800000e+01
3.414286e+01    3.700000e+01
3.416364e+01    3.600000e+01
3.418519e+01    3.500000e+01
3.420755e+01    3.400000e+01
3.423077e+01    3.300000e+01
3.400971e+01    3.200000e+01
3.400000e+01    3.195652e+01
3.378431e+01    3.100000e+01
3.355446e+01    3.000000e+01
3.332000e+01    2.900000e+01
3.308081e+01    2.800000e+01
4.000000e+00    1.100000e+01
5.716327e+01    1.600000e+01
5.700000e+01    1.585714e+01
5.683673e+01    1.600000e+01
5.600000e+01    1.683673e+01
5.585714e+01    1.700000e+01
5.600000e+01    1.713793e+01
}\mydata


\pgfplotsset{colormap={jet}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,128) rgb255(1cm)=(0,0,255)rgb255(3cm)=(0,255,255) rgb255(5cm)=(255,255,0) rgb255(7cm)=(255,0,0) rgb255(8cm)=(128,0,0)}}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                width=.93\textwidth,
                height=.45\textheight,
                xmin=7,
                xmax=67,
                ymin=7,
                ymax=67,
                axis x line=bottom,
                axis y line=left,
                ticks=none,
                colormap={myjet}{samples of colormap=(20 of jet)},
                colormap access=piecewise constant,
                colorbar,
                colorbar style={
                        width=8pt,
                        ytick={0,2,...,20},
                        yticklabel style={
                        /pgf/number format/.cd,
                            fixed,
                            fixed zerofill,
                            precision=1
                        }
                },clip=false]

            \addplot[thick,contour prepared,contour prepared format=matlab,/pgfplots/contour/labels=false] table[col sep = tab] {\mydata};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add the output of TeXworks to your question please, so we know what output you are expecting?

Comment: This might be a bug in Foxit. In fact, opening the resulting pdf in firefox (pdf.js) results in the same wrong output as your "foxit" screen shot: some viewers simply have defects in their implementation. If the acrobat reader also shows something as on the right, I will need to search for defects. My acrobat reader displays the correct result. If it really is a viewer issue, you should take the PDF and submit a bug report for the foxit reader.

Comment: for the records: the broken shading in firefox (pdf.js) is an open defect under https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/6231

Comment: I now tested with Adobe Reader DC and indeed the result is correct.